# Canon pro pixma 100s borderless prints with borders

Tags: canon, printer

I have bought canon pixma pro 100s and canon a4 paper. I wanted to print borderless, both with lightroom and Mac JPG app. If I go for borderless print I get a print with 2 mm borders on top and left, which is unwanted. What should I do to remove these borders?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about printing and not about photography.

Comment: @xenoid for real? This is a printer designed for photographers who use it to make prints from photographs, either digital or scanned film. The print is the final stage of the photograph...so how would a question about creating said print be off topic?

Comment: Because the question would be exactly the same trying to print a logo from AI or Inkscape, and IMHO the answer lies in a Canon printer support forum (and could be that the paper is shifted in the transports mechanism). Then it's only a vote, if I'm alone, so be it.

Comment: Do you get to see a print preview from these apps before printing? Does the print preview show the 2mm border? Using Photoshop and this printer, I get a preview that shows the borders or lack thereof. But I always print with borders. The printer has to hold on to the paper somehow while printing, so this may be the best it can do.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do to remove these borders?

Use a razor and straightedge, or purchase a paper trimmer.

Answer (score 2):

I also own this printer.

You basically have 2 options in the Canon Print Studio Pro Software that is supplied:

1. Print with the option borderless on the layout tab. Note: This will give you borderless prints on papers that Canon deems compatible with that, but the print will lose a safety margin around the image. You need to plan ahead and include that margin.
2. You print with borders, but set the borders to a very small amount. This will **NOT** print borderless, but you get the full image. Excess margin has to be trimmed off with a cutter.

Side note: Having to include a safety margin for full page borderless printing is pretty standard, even with professional printing. Printing services will always specify, how much safety margin they expect from you. This may vary with the precision of their printing press.

Answer (score 0):

I semi resolved the problem. I have run head calibration multiple time. Now the problem is way smaller, but still exists. If I want to have very small borders it will not work, they will be uneven. If I want to have big borders, like 25 mm it works. Borderless also works, but I set up rescalling and loose some small amount of picture.